# How to edit and modify the main page of Luma theme?

Tags: magento2, theme, image, edit

For the Luma theme, how to:

- How to reach and edit the main page of magento 2 Luma theme?
- How to replace the images there with my images?
- How to edit the hot sellers section?
- How to reach and edit the "What's new" page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a static block with the ID of `home-page-block`, this contains the homepage content for the Luma theme.

To access this login to the admin and go to content > blocks and you should see `home-page-block` in the list. In the right hand column click on select, and the option to edit should then dropdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How to reach and edit the "What's new" page?

The content > block > New Block has the content for the "what's new page"

The reason for the what's new page to display the static block in the firstplace is the content > widget > New Products Category Content. Here is the link under Widget options which specify the new block to be displayed on the What's New (cat 38) on the Main Content Top position.

[image: widget]

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the images of main-page magento 2 Luma theme. You have to go admin-view click on CONTENT tab > Blocks and you should see `home-page-block` in the rows. You should see a select dropdown under `Action` column click on it and select edit. You should see a Home Page Block page and this page contains `Show/Hide Editor` button click on it and change the images you wanted to change.

[image]