# Cannot see any blocks in Magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks

Magento version - Community Edition 2.1.1

Machine - AWS EC2

OS - Ubuntu - 14.04

Php - 5.6

MySql - 5.6

Theme - Default Luma

I have installed magento 2 without sample data. 
Everything is working smoothly but I could not see any blocks under this tab.

**Admin Login -> Content -> Blocks**

It shows ' We could not found any records'

Is this the expected behaviour ? How can I add default blocks?

I have already explored this https://community.magento.com/t5/Theming-Layout-Design-Questions/No-default-Content-Elements-Blocks-listed-in-admin-backend-e-g/m-p/41872#M598 , but this is not exactly I am looking for.

Even my database `cms-block` table is empty.

I am new to magento2 and really stuck here. 
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: If you installed without sample data then there will not be any CMS blocks until you decide to create some.

Comment: @Aaron What about the Luma theme blocks. Can I somehow use luma's block?

Comment: there are no blocks on the luma theme unless you install the sample data. you can just create a new block yourself or install the sample data.  with the sample data you you will get the following blocks on the homepage: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104749/how-to-edit-and-modify-the-main-page-of-luma-theme

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is expected behaviour.

Your blocks may depend on your theme.

For example if you purchase theme you may see more blocks.

Go ahead and create a block. This block can be imported using widgets in your pages(Home page for example) or even block inside another block.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento without sample will not have default data.

So you should create cms block/pages for that or install a theme that will auto create default data for you.