# Resource (HTML theme)for learning Magento 2 theme integration

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, rwd-theme

Where i can find the Magento 2 **THEME** (**HTML**) not the completed developed theme.

---

- I want to learn Magento 2 theme integration.
- By **THEME** i mean to say a collection of simple ***html*** pages like home(index.html) , listing, detail, checkout etc...using those i want to develop the original magento pages.

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can find info at Magento 2 dev docs - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-general.html

To get the template files, go to the files in the vender/magento/{{module_name}} grab what you are looking to work with and copy it over to a custom theme.

if You would like to work with product templates

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

You can copy and modify it in

```
app/design/frontend/{{vendor_namespace}}/{{theme_name}}/Magento_Catalog/templates/list.phtml
```

Hope that It will cover Your question.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response...but i need the theme which contains index.html(home page),listing and detail page html which i can integrate with magento with your suggested way...

Comment: To edit home page - check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104749/how-to-edit-and-modify-the-main-page-of-luma-theme